# Multivariable function critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)-y\sin(x)+\frac{y^2}{2}$$

My task is to find the critical points of this multivariable function (Determine the set of critical points of the function).
Now I found the partial derivative to be $$ f^\prime_x= \left(x - y\right) \cos{\left(x \right)} \\ f^\prime_y=y - \sin{\left(x \right)}$$

Wolfram Alpha says the critical point(s) is/are at $x=y$? How do I get the above in that form? The best I could do was get it in the form $x-y\sec(x)+\tan(x)=y$

Any help?

Comment: Only one critical point is located on the line $y=x$. There are an infinite number of critical points on the lines $y=\pm 1$

Comment: How did you compute that?

Comment: When does $f_x=0$ ?

Comment: When x=y or when x=0 but what about $f\prime_y$?

Comment: Try again, that's not correct

Comment: Multiples of $x= \pi/2$

Comment: That's closer, but still not correct

Comment: And multiples on $3\pi /2$ since these are the only ones that work at $y= \pm1$

Comment: I don't think you understood what my comment meant. $\pi$ is a multiple of $\pi/2$, but it does not work

Comment: $2\pi n$ multiples